# VS2010 SDK - Adding Display Items to the Fonts and Colors options dialog

Tags: visual-studio-2010, resharper, visual-studio-sdk

I'm trying to add custom Display Items to the Fonts and Colors dialog. I can successfully save and retrieve colors using the [IVsFontAndColorStorage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.interop.ivsfontandcolorstorage.aspx) service but the items do not appear in the list of Display Items. I have tried following this blog [post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dr._ex/archive/2005/06/03/425099.aspx) about adding a custom category. My category appeared but only with the default display items. My real goal is to add my custom colors to the "Text Editor" category. ReSharper does a similar thing.

[image: Fonts and Colors Dialog]

Have anyone had experience with this? Is there a nice tutorial out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually went a different route. This thread has the details on how to accomplish it: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vseditor/thread/ed463657-6a36-4e33-b313-b2923cc81a74

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing an Editor Extension and wondered the same thing. It as easy as decorating the attributes you want to appear with UserVisible(true). See this thread for more information.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/cef23a9e-db87-4683-a4be-d18561e8bded